# Sliding multiple div's from left to right

Tags: javascript, html, css, element, sliding

I'm trying to slide multiple divs of p tags from right to left (or vice versa) but instead of sliding them from right to left they are all showing up one after the other. How do i show just one and then slide the next from the left(or right) and so on?
thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p><br />
    <ul class="actions">
      <li><a href="#" class="button special big">Get 
        Details</a></li>    
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="slide2">
    <p>Epes di ameb latota ed atem</p><br />
    <ul class="actions">
      <li><a href="#" class="button special big">More Info</a> 
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $('#slider').animate({right: "2000px"}, "slow", function () {
    $('#slider img:first-child').appendTo('#slider');
    $('#slider').css('right', '0');
  });
}, 4000);
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

Comment: So you want it to be similar to a stack of cards where you slide the one off the top to reveal the one underneath?

Comment: no i want something like this: https://www.ylaw.ca/
notice how the title is sliding to reveal new ones? and back again. that's what i'm trying to get.

Comment: If you're able to use an external library, I suggest using boostrap's carousel. It's exactly what you're looking for. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: yes exactly what i'm looking for but would you know the edit in javascript or css i would need to make it automatic after say 4 seconds?
thanks a lot man!

Comment: Yeah. Are you fine with using Boostrap (the link I provided)? If so, I’ll post an example with it which changes the slide every 4 seconds

Comment: Yeah i'm fine with it thanks. let me know when you post it !

Comment: Just got back from work. Posted it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a carousel using Bootstrap. Change the `data-interval` value from 4000 to whatever time interval in milliseconds you'd like the images to transition in.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.hdwall.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/hdwall.xyz-Pink-Lowpoly-Abstract-Samsung-Galaxy-S9-Stock931866586-1280x720.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/350636663_1280x720.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://wallpapersite.com/images/pages/pic_w/8931.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

More information and Bootstrap documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: Amazing! thanks so much. One little thing though. when i run it on an editor (sublime) sometimes the images (or text in my case) pause for much  longer than 3 seconds. Feels like a bug. Do you know about this? Any fixes?
thanks for the help.

Comment: @UrielBitton Hmm, I'm not 100% sure. If you can post your code to a jsfiddle and link it here, I can take a look. Also, if you wouldn't mind, could you accept my answer?

Comment: Oh of course! New to stack overflow haha
Posting it now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/UrielBitto/u8crmd3a/2/

Here, sometimes the sliding text gets stuck at "Lorem ipsum" for more than 3 seconds
Play around with reloading th epage if it works for you.

Comment: @UrielBitton The jsfiddle you posted seems to work fine for me. I can't reproduce the issue you described of slides getting stuck. Are you still experiencing a problem?

Comment: It's good thanks man! You mind checking out my latest post? Thanks a lot. will give you votes :)